# Why is background-originn and background-clip working properly for me?

Tags: css

I have already checked `stackoverflow` but it hasn't completely solved my issue.

From my understanding background-clip dictates where an image is to be cut or what part of it is view-able, so for example if background-clip is set to content-box, the image may extend past the content area but only the content area would be visible as if it's a window into the background-image. Where as background-origin doesn't dictate where the image is cut, but where its positioned,

so if for example  I have background-origin set to padding-box, the background-image starts at padding, not under the border. In other words background-clip controls what part of the box model the background-image is view-able in and background-origin controls what part of the box model the image starts at. Correct?

When I set background-clip to border-box, however the images doesn't get clipped at the border only like it should from my understand, the right and left go to the edge of the border, like expected but then the top and bottom get clipped on the inside edge as is padding-box. The same result happens if I set the background-origin to padding-box, top,bottom and left and right are clipped differently.

Also if I set the background-origin to content box it results in the right stretching past the padding to the left and right, from my understand this states that the image should start and stay in the content area. Am I understanding this incorrectly or am I doing something wrong? I'm having trouble seeing what I'm doing wrong since this seems quite straight forward and for the same reason, I dont see what I could be miss understanding.

https://jsfiddle.net/eeqso497/6/

```
  div{
            background-image: url("https://tse3.mm.bing.net     /th?id=OIP.IspmxU5Ezg8E94QsVE04vgEsDx&pid=15.1&P=0&w=199&h=161");
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-size: cover;
            background-position: 30%;
            border: 10px dashed red;
            width: 150px;
            height: 150px;
            padding: 50px;
            background-clip: border-box;
            background-origin: content-box;
 }
```

Comment: Perhaps you could make it more clear what the desired effect is?

Comment: thanks for the reply, I'm not looking for any particular effect, I'm just trying to understand background-clip and background-origin, but they dont seem to be working as describe by stackoverflow and various other resources and I'm trying understand what the issue is. for example if its set to background-clip, border-box, why is it clipped at the padding at the top and bottom, shouldnt it be clipped at the border on all four side not just two?

Comment: Alright, I've added some links for you to read up about those CSS properties.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what you're asking, but assuming this is the effect you want:

[image]

Part of the problem is that you have 50px of padding around the div (the background image stays on the div itself). Then, you need to set `background-clip` to `content-box`. Setting it to `border-box` would result in this:

[image]

Just change your CSS to this:

```css
div {
  background-image: url("https://tse3.mm.bing.net/th?id=OIP.IspmxU5Ezg8E94QsVE04vgEsDx&pid=15.1&P=0&w=199&h=161");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: 30%;
  border: 10px dashed red;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background-clip: content-box;
}
```

```html
<div>
</div>
```

[CodePen](https://codepen.io/AquatuzMagnus/pen/zzqgxX)

**EDIT:** As the OP only wants to know how `background-clip` and `background-origin` work;
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/background-origin
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-clip